# Office.js, Office.context.mailbox.item.cc.getAsync does not work

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm working to create a Outlook add-in using office-js.

I need to get cc and to of an e-mail message.

Since I read these pages, I write this code. However, when cc.getAsync and to.getAsync works nothing whereas body.getAsync returns collect body of the message.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox.item?view=common-js-preview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.recipients?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true

```
// It does not work though I expect to appear cc of the message on taskpane of my add-in
 const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
 item.cc.getAsync(function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = `<h2 class="message">${asyncResult.value}</h2>`;
        document.getElementById("message").style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    });
```

```
// same here
const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
item.to.getAsync(function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = `<h2 class="message">${asyncResult.value}</h2>`;
        document.getElementById("message").style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    });
```

```
// on the other hand, I can see the body of  the message on my taskpane
item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, function callback(result) {
    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = `<h2 class="message">${result.value}</h2>`;
      document.getElementById("message").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  });
```

Comment: When and where do you run the code mentioned on your post? Is it on the edit item? Did you try to save the item first?

Comment: Can you confirm platform, version, and if you are running your provided code in read or compose mode? The result for your first snippet should look something like [{"emailAddress":"EMAIL","displayName":"VALUE","recipientType":"TYPE"}]. Can you try logging the output?